# 404 redirect issue after editing .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

A while ago when I was fiddling with my .htaccess file the default 404 error messages stopped working. Now, the error pages look like this 
http://www.minecraftserverland.com/s2/1

My .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ /serverdisplay.php?server_id=$1
RewriteRule ^s2/(.*)$ /serverdisplay2.php?server_id=$1
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^vote/(.*)$ /vote.php?server_id=$1
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType img/button.png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType img/feeback.png "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType css/orbit-1.2.3.css "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType css/other.css "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType css/type/SourceSansPro-Regular-webfont.woff "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType img/Delete-icon.png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType img/MinecraftServerLand2.png "access plus 10 days"
ExpiresByType img/ajax-loader.gif "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType img/background.png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType img/banner/6b1ebf3c92.png "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType img/banner/962f857d10.png "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType img/banner/b26908a721.jpg "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType img/banner/c29f43e31f.jpg "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType img/banner/d68c807fde.jpg "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType js/jquery.validate.pack.js "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType js/jquery.placeholder.js "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType img/orbit/timer-black.png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType js/jquery.contactable.js "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

I tried adding a custom redirect with

```
ErrorDocument 404 /home/minecra/public_html/errorpage.php
```

but that did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting a 404 is because `/serverdisplay2.php` doesn't exist on your server.

The reason your `ErrorDocument` isn't working is because `http://www.minecraftserverland.com/home/minecra/public_html/errorpage.php` also doesn't exist. The `ErrorDocument` [documentation says](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument):

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve. Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the browser.

That means if it begins with a `/`, then it assumes it's a web-path relative to the document root, not your server's root. What you probably want is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.php
```